# Use seperate existing database of users for django login

Tags: django

Is it possible to use an existing database of users without integrating it to the database of your django project. If yes, would i be able to use the user.is_authenticated and other django auths? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django supports both [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/) and [custom auth backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/), so the answer is a plain simple "yes, and yes".

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any link that might be helpful?(something that has an example using a different user database and configured  a custom auth)

Comment: The doc has examples for both features. Note that those are totally orthogonal concerns - you could have a distinct db for users while still using django's default auth or have a custom user model (or custom auth backend) using the same db as your other models etc... Really, start with the official doc, check the details for custom user models, custom auth backends and multi-db, and you should find out which features apply to your own use case.